# AJAX Contact form unable to find API Route, throwing 404 Error in console in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have a user profile page (index.php | View) where any user can fill the contact form and send a message to particular user(whose profile is open). when i am trying to submit from it give me 404 Error and unable to find the route for contact_user Controller function.
here is my code for the same

here is the contact form code from profile view

```
<!-- Contact -->
<section class="resume-section" id="contact">
    <div class="resume-section-content">
        <h2 class="mb-5">Contact</h2>
        <form method="POST" name="contact_us_form" id="contact_us_form">
            <?php
            foreach ($user_data as $key) {
                ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="id" value="<?= $key->user_id ?>">
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_form_name" name="contact_form_name"
                    placeholder="Your Name">
                <span class="text-danger" id="error_name"></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_form_mobile" name="contact_form_mobile"
                    placeholder="Your Mobile" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}">
                <span class="text-danger" id="error_mobile"></span>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact_form_email" name="contact_form_email"
                    placeholder="Your Email">
                <span class="text-danger" id="error_email"></span>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_form_subject" name="contact_form_subject"
                    placeholder="Message Subject">
                <span class="text-danger" id="error_subject"></span>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="contact_form_message" name="contact_form_message"
                    placeholder="Message" rows="3"></textarea>
                <span class="text-danger" id="error_message"></span>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="thankyou-message" id="thankyou-message" style="color:green"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="contact_us" name="contact_us" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

here is my javascript Ajax code

```
jQuery('#contact_us_form').on('submit', function(e){
        // alert('hello');
        e.preventDefault();

        // Name Validation
        if ($.trim($('#contact_form_name').val()).length == 0) {
            error_name = 'Please enter your name';
            $('#error_name').text(error_name);
        } else {
            error_name = '';
            $('#error_name').text(error_name);
        }


        // Mobile Validation
        if ($.trim($('#contact_form_mobile').val()).length == 0) {
            error_mobile = 'Please enter your Mobile';
            $('#error_mobile').text(error_mobile);
        } else {
            error_mobile = '';
            $('#error_mobile').text(error_mobile);
        }

        // Email Validation
        if ($.trim($('#contact_form_email').val()).length == 0) {
            error_email = 'Please enter your Email';
            $('#error_email').text(error_email);
        } else {
            error_email = '';
            $('#error_email').text(error_email);
        }

        // Subject Validation
        if ($.trim($('#contact_form_subject').val()).length == 0) {
            error_subject = 'Please enter Message Subject';
            $('#error_subject').text(error_subject);
        } else {
            error_subject = '';
            $('#error_subject').text(error_subject);
        }

        // Message Validation
        if ($.trim($('#contact_form_message').val()).length == 0) {
            error_message = 'Please enter Your Message';
            $('#error_message').text(error_message);
        } else {
            error_message = '';
            $('#error_message').text(error_message);
        }

        if (error_name != '' || error_mobile != '' || error_email != '' || error_subject != '' ||
        error_message != '') {
        return false;
        }else{
            var data = {
            'user_id': $('#user_id').val(),
            'contact_name': $('#contact_form_name').val(),
            'contact_mobile': $('#contact_form_mobile').val(),
            'contact_email': $('#contact_form_email').val(),
            'contact_subject': $('#contact_form_subject').val(),
            'contact_message': $('#contact_form_message').val(),
            };
            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "/Home/contact_user",
                // headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    jQuery('#contact_us_form')['0'].reset();
                    jQuery('#contact_us').val('SUBMIT');
                    jQuery('#contact_us').attr('disabled', false);

                    alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                    alertify.success("Done");
                    // response.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

here are my Routes

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index'); // Default route, if no username redirect to welcome view
$routes->post('/Home/contact_user', 'Home::contact_user'); //contact form API Route, submit form data to this route
$routes->get('/(:any)', 'Home::user/$1'); // User Profile, if username found, show user profile
```

and here is my contact_user function from Home Controller

```
public function contact_user(){
    $Home_Model = new \App\Models\Home_model();
    
    $data = [
        'user_id' => $this->request->getPost('user_id'),
        'contact_name' => $this->request->getPost('contact_name'),
        'contact_mobile' => $this->request->getPost('contact_mobile'),
        'contact_email' => $this->request->getPost('contact_email'),
        'contact_subject' => $this->request->getPost('contact_subject'),
        'contact_message' => $this->request->getPost('contact_message')
    ];

    $Home_Model->save($data);
    $data = ['status' => 'successful'];
    return $this->response->setJSON($data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need to wrap the ajax url property in the base_url() function like base_url('/Home/contact_user')

Comment: Thank you, its work. we can not use CI 4 function base_url() in js so i create a hidden input field with value base URL and use it as variable in my js and it worked

Comment: Awesome! Glad it works for you.